# Зонт, парасоль чи зонтик?

Tags: вибір-слова

Яке слово найкраще використовувати на позначення предмету, який захищає від дощу? [Зонт](http://sum.in.ua/s/zont), [зонтик](http://sum.in.ua/s/zontyk), [парасоль](http://sum.in.ua/s/parasolj) - всі 3 слова знаходимо в [СУМі]. Однак, біля слів **зонт**, **зонтик** бачимо позначку *рідко*. У [Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F) знаходжу що ці 2 слова *розмовні.* То чи буде нормативним вживання слів **зонт, зонтик** (адже позначка *рідко*, яку бачимо в СУМі, не означає ненормативності слововживання.

Answer (score 3):

У ботаниці зросійщені терміни для суцвіття "зонтик" чи таксону "зонтичні", силомиць нав'язані в 1930-х роках для уподіблення української термінології до російської, нині замінено на питомі українські терміни "окружок", "окружкові". У випадку латинський видових епітетів "umbellatum", їх краще перекладати українською як "парасольковий" і не вживати зросійщене "зонтичний".

Олександр Пономарів у статті [Повернення до національних засад в українській термінології](https://science.lpnu.ua/uk/terminologiya/vsi-vypusky/visnyk-no-453-2002/povernennya-do-nacionalnyh-zasad-v-ukrayinskiy):

> У ботанічній термінології тривалий час був уживаний оригінальний український термін на позначення родини рослин *окружкові*, але в 50-х роках минулого століття його замінено запозиченим з російської мови *зонтичні*.

Comment: Вітаємо на цьому сайті і дякуємо за ґрунтовну відповідь. Варто зауважити, що у запитанні прямо йшлося про *«предмет, який захищає від дощу»*. Тому у майбутньому, будь ласка, зосереджуйтеся на безпосередній відповіді на запитання. Сторонні значення згаданого слова можуть бути *однією із частин* більш широкої відповіді, але не єдиною її частиною.

Answer (score 2):

Вам просто варто було подивитися новий СУМ-20:

> [ЗО́НТИК](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=37843&page=1184), а, ч. 1. **розм**. Те саме, що парасо́лька 1. Зложивши руки за спину і обпершись на високий і товстий з парусини зонтик, він стояв проти халабуди (Панас Мирний); Софія Леонівна вскочила в кабінет, вже убрана в дорогу, з зонтиком у руці, така весела, така радісна (І. Нечуй-Левицький); Гликерія поспішно, нервово бере з брички килим, який був на сидінні, свою кофту, зонтик, пальто і подає Іванові (В. Винниченко).

...

> [ЗОНТ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=37842&page=1184), а, ч. 1. **розм**. Те саме, що зо́нтик 1; парасолька. Усе узбережжя .. розквітло китайськими різнобарвними зонтами і квітчастими хусточками жінок (О. Сизоненко); Гуляють [люди], сидять на лавочках в затінку дерев, під зонтами за столиками морозиво їдять, милуються розквітлими трояндами (Г. Тарасюк); У вільному просторі в кінці класу їх – розчепірених зонтів – зібралася ціла армада. Зонти сушилися (Любко Дереш).

Найсучасніший тлумачний словник української мови каже, що обидва ці слова розмовні. Отже, ви можете користуватися ними в приватній бесіді або дописах на фейсбуці, але в офіційних документах, статтях, які не передбачають розмовного стилю, тощо ці слова вживати не варто.

Answer (score 0):

Перш за все, варто зазначити, що усі три слова можна вживати, адже,як ви і зазначили, вони зустрічаються в СУМі. Однак, згідно до [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F) слово "зонт", а відповідно і "зонтик" (від якого воно походить "зонт") вживаються рідко в українській мові і більше поширені в російській.

Тому краще вживати такі слова як "парасолька", "парасоль", "парасоля", тощо. Також Вікіпедія пропонує варіант "дощар", однак його немає в СУМі, тому гадаю, що із вживання цього слова слід бути обреженим.

Comment: Але словник чужомовних слів Павла Штепи має [дощарка](//archive.org/stream/shtepa1977/shtepa1977_djvu.txt). А взагалі, це дещо дивненько, немає суто нейтрального, нагадаю, що _зонтік_ та _парасоля_ мають в основі _сонце_.

Comment: Я не зовсім добре зрозумів, що ви мали на увазі, коли написали, що зонтік та парасоля мають в основі сонце

Comment: Слово _сонце_ = [_sole_](//it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sole) з італійського _parasole_ = [_zon_](//nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zon) з низоземського _zondek_ (очевидно, _-тик_ не є пестливістю, а таким собі запозиченням через фінської в московську). Обидва слова буквально значать _проти сонця_ та _захист від сонця_.

Comment: @follower Навпаки, "зонтик" походить від нідерл. zonnedek «навіс від сонця». Через деякий закінчення "-ік" було осмислене як зменшувальний суфікс і від "зонтік" було створене "нормальне" слово "зонт".